# The Heat Kernel to Solve an Initial Value Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, heat-equation, initial-value-problems

The Question I have is:
$$u_t(x, t) − ku_{xx}(x, t) = 0$$ $$∀x ∈ \mathbb{R}, t > 0$$

subject to-

$u(x, 0) = x^2 − 3x − 1$ $∀x ∈ \mathbb{R}.$

I started off with

$$u(x,t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4kt}(y^2-3y-1)dy$$

and then I made $σ=y-x$ therefore I get

$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi kt}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^\frac{-σ^2}{4kt}((σ+x)^2-3(σ+x)-1)dσ$$

that simplifies to:

$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi kt}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^\frac{-σ^2}{4kt}(σ^2+2σx+x^2-3σ-3x-1)dσ$$

But from here I'm not sure how to integrate the answer and get any further. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute
$$u(x,t)=v(t)+x^2-3x-1$$
For $v(t)$ we get ODE problem
$$v'(t)=2k,\quad v(0)=0.$$
$\Rightarrow$ $v(t)=2kt$

Solution of Initial Value Problem is
$$u(x,t)=2kt+x^2-3x-1$$